# File recovery window server 2008 networked drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, data-recovery

I lost files when I was tying to move them from one folder to another on a networked drive. The files are not in the original folder or destination folder. I checked rcycle bin the files are not there. I did a search on all drive ther files cannot be found. How can I recover those files/ I sthere a free software I can use?

Comment: Are you running VSS on this server? Do you have snapshots enabled?

Comment: Have you got a backup? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files deleted from a networked drive do not go to the recycle bin on the client or server, they are simply gone.  If the files are missing, you will need to restore them from some backup.  VSS snapshots would be the quickest way to restore them, if you have them enabled on that volume.